# I need to build a python script that will check if the directory is existing in remote windows machine

Tags: python

I want to build a python script that will tell me which host machine dont have the following directory that I'm looking.

I tried this code but it is only supported for local machine.

```py
import os

def CheckIsDir(directory):
    return os.path.isdir(directory)

if CheckIsDir(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Kaspersky Lab\NetworkAgent"):
    print ('Yes')

else: 
    print ('No')
```

Comment: Is the remote host mountable or shareable like a network map drive? How do you plan on connecting to the remote server?

Comment: how do you check it without python ? Do you get error when you use it with Python ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.